# Most Active Contributors Weekly Report! (May 2017 Week 4)

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors

Welcome our SharePoint Stack Exchange valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last week.

## This report includes the following awards:

1. Weekly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Commented Award.
14. Most Viewed Questions Award.
15. Most Edited Questions Award.
16. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

**Weekly Leader Board.** You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/week/sharepoint/2017-05-28)

### [image]

## Most Active Contributors Award.

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                    315
2   Waqas Sarwar MVP            235
3   Venkat Konjeti              166
4   Danny '365CSI' Engelman     165
5   S Merchant                  160
```

---

## Most Active Editors Award.

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   InnovaITve Solutions       58
2   M.Qassas                   47
3   Mike                       22
4   Muhammad Zeeshan Tahir     16
5   Robert Lindgren            15
```

---

## Most Active Voters Award.

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   R_Viper                    120
2   Gerry                      117
3   Danny '365CSI' Engelman    53
4   M.Qassas                   47
5   P S                        39
```

---

## Most Close Votes Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Robert Lindgren              4
2   M.Qassas                     4
3   Mike                         3
```

---

## Most First Post Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                    19
2   moe                         13
3   hoffie4                     8
4   Waqas Sarwar MVP            7
5   P S                         6
```

---

## Most Late Answer Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   moe                          6
2   M.Qassas                     5
3   hoffie4                      4
4   Robert Lindgren              3
```

---

## Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Waqas Sarwar MVP             4
2   Asad Refai                   3
```

---

## Most Reopen Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Robert Lindgren              5
```

---

## Most Suggested Edit Review Award.

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   P S                          18
2   M.Qassas                     17
3   Robert Lindgren              13
4   Dikesh Gandhi                12
5   Mike                         11
```

---

## Highest Votes Questions Award.

1. [When to use RBS and when not to](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216930/when-to-use-rbs-and-when-not-to)

   - Quest Owner: Omegacron.
   - Votes: 8.
2. [Searching by a site column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217033/searching-by-a-site-column)

   - Quest Owner: user67560.
   - Votes: 5.
3. [Does the database size change after migrating?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216969/does-the-database-size-change-after-migrating/216970#216970)

   - Quest Owner: Boland.
   - Votes: 5.

---

## Highest Votes Answers Award.

1. [Set Modern Page as a Home Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216932/set-modern-page-as-a-home-page/216943#216943)

   - Answer Owner: S Merchant.
   - Votes: 7.
2. [Does the database size change after migrating?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216969/does-the-database-size-change-after-migrating/216970#216970)

   - Answer Owner: Waqas Sarwar MVP.
   - Votes: 6.
3. [Set SharePoint Group Owner of a SharePoint group through PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216996/set-sharepoint-group-owner-of-a-sharepoint-group-through-powershell/216997#216997)

   - Answer Owner: Gautam Sheth.
   - Votes: 5.

---

## Most Commented Award.

1. [AppFabricCaching Service DOWN](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216963/appfabriccaching-service-down/216964#216964)

   - Comments: 16
2. [How to fetch a user email and pass it to iFrame?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216882/how-to-fetch-a-user-email-and-pass-it-to-iframe/216918#216918)

   - Comments: 10
3. [Does the database size change after migrating?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216969/does-the-database-size-change-after-migrating/216970#216970)

   - Comments: 10

---

## Most Viewed Questions Award.

1. [When to use RBS and when not to](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216930/when-to-use-rbs-and-when-not-to)

   - Views: 156.
2. [Set Modern Page as a Home Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216932/set-modern-page-as-a-home-page/216943#216943)

   - Views: 98.
3. [Set SharePoint Group Owner of a SharePoint group through PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216996/set-sharepoint-group-owner-of-a-sharepoint-group-through-powershell/216997#216997)

   - Views: 86.

---

## Most Edited Questions Award.

1. [Can't login to VM SharePoint 2016 from the network](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216707/cant-login-to-vm-sharepoint-2016-from-the-network)

   - Edits: 10.
2. [“Unable to display the webpart…” error at the first time and after refreshing the page it goes off](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216872/unable-to-display-the-webpart-error-at-the-first-time-and-after-refreshing)

   - Edits: 7.

---

## 1st Top Contributors list.

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [InnovaITve Solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/66704/innovaitve-solutions) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [R_Viper](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/65156/r-viper) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [Robert Lindgren](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15141/robert-lindgren) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [moe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21441/moe) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [Waqas Sarwar MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21563/waqas-sarwar-mvp) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [Robert Lindgren](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15141/robert-lindgren) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [P S](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/41198/p-s) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [Omegacron](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20982/omegacron) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [S Merchant](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/49449/s-merchant) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Commented Award.**

    - [AppFabricCaching Service DOWN](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216963/appfabriccaching-service-down/216964#216964)
13. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [When to use RBS and when not to](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216930/when-to-use-rbs-and-when-not-to)

---

Finally, we fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & and precious advice for this report!

Comment: Great initiative!!! Will you(mods) generate  this every week ?

Comment: Hi @GautamSheth, thanks for your valuable feedback! I planned to prepare this report weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly as I said in my Electoral Program but the decision of republishing this report periodically depend on SE members feedback :) so I will wait until the end of the week to get the final feedback!

Comment: Well I really appreciate your effort in generating the report and the contributions of our the community members :) 
I would suggest also that you wait till end of this week for this to gain traction, it might pick up afterwards. Also, have a feeling that not many members would appreciate it weekly, so generating it monthly, quarterly and yearly would be sufficient.  One other thing i would to see is top contributing users based on countries (if that's possible and not too time consuming, like top 10 countries)

Comment: Great idea to add countries but unfortunately, not all contributors added their country so I added the profile link :) thanks again for your appreciation :)